# Formula / math calculations for moving a player forward based on direction facing

Tags: math, formulas, algebra, calculation

Im quite bad at maths, and need help moving the player forward for a tool im working on for a game, but the only information i have is what direction the player is facing, and i need to translate that into x and y coordinate increments or decrements.

So if we say M is the direction the player is facing and M goes from 0.00000 to 5.9999999 and then wraps back to 0.000, with the following being correct:

```
0 = North
1.5 = West
3 = South
4.5 = East
```

If i want to move the player north, i would do y + amount, south would be y - amount, and if i want to move the player east, i would do x - amount, and west would be x + amount.

So moving the player forward is easy when they are facing an absolute direction, e.g M is 0 so i just add say 5 to the y coordinate. But if the player is facing say 1.2 which is nearly west, what would i add to X and Y to move them forwards exactly, presumably i would add say 5 to x, and some percentage of 5 to y.

Looking for the help of anyone with a knack for this kind of stuff and any help is greatly appreciated. Psuedo code and help of any kind is appreciated, thank you all!

Comment: Look up sine and cosine

Comment: Alternatively polar to Cartesian coordinate conversion.

Comment: Multiply M by 60 to get degrees, btw, or by pi/3 to get radians.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `x` and `y` are the current coordinates, `dir` is the current direction in your 1-6 units, and `amount` is the distance to move, your new coordinates would be

```
angle = dir * pi / 3
newx = x + amount * sin(angle)
newy = y + amount * cos(angle)
```

If you truly just want the decrements, just remove the `x` and the `y` from the formulas.

Note that this uses trigonometry. Most computer languages need the angle to be in radians, so the first line converts the given direction angle to radians.

Also note that your directions for the direction angle values and for your directions for increasing x and y coordinates are non-standard. Therefore those who know trig may be confused at using `cos` with the x-coordinate and `sin` for the y-coordinate, since these are not standard. But that is what is needed in your case. As @HighPerformanceMark just pointed out in a comment, you should consider changing your direction angles and your x- and y-coordinates to something more standard. The one that he suggests, 0 degrees for north and 90 degrees for east, is standard in navigation. Another standard, used in trigonometry, is 0 degrees or radians for east and pi/2 radians or 90 degrees for north.